# Conditionally replace the values in columns to value in another column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I tried really hard to find an answer to this and I apologize if it's a duplicate.

I'll make some dummy data to explain my question.

```
tibble(a=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), sample1 = c(0, 1, 1), sample2 = c(1, 1, 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a sample1 sample2
 <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.1       0       1
2   0.2       1       1
3   0.3       1       0
```

How to I conditionally change the values in columns **sample1** and **sample2** so that if they are equal to one, they take on the value of **a**.

The resulting tibble should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a sample1 sample2
 <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.1       0     0.1
2   0.2     0.2     0.2
3   0.3     0.3       0
```

Ideally I don't want to do this for each individual sample column (I have >100 sample columns), so a way to loop over columns would be better (although I know loops are the devil).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` with `ifelse`:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('sample')), funs(ifelse(. == 1, a, .)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      a sample1 sample2
#  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1   0.1     0.0     0.1
#2   0.2     0.2     0.2
#3   0.3     0.3     0.0
```

`vars(starts_with('sample'))` matches all columns that starts with `sample` and `mutate_at` applies the function `funs(ifelse(. == 1, a, .))` to each column; `.` stands for the matched column here.

---

If you are sure all the samples columns contain only `1` and `0`, it can be shortened as:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('sample')), funs(. * a))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      a sample1 sample2
#  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1   0.1     0.0     0.1
#2   0.2     0.2     0.2
#3   0.3     0.3     0.0
```

Comment: Man...I tried to play around with mutate_at for some time, but my fault was using replace() instead of ifelse(). This worked perfectly...thanks!

Comment: `replace` was my first thought as well. But it requires the condition and replacement have the same length or recyclable, which is not as convenient as `ifelse` here.

Answer (score 0):

Non-dplyr solution using `which()`:

```
> t=tibble(a=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), sample1 = c(0, 1, 1), sample2 = c(1, 1, 0))

> whichRows=which(t$sample1==t$sample2)

> t[whichRows,c('sample1','sample2')]<-t[whichRows,'a']

> t
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a sample1 sample2
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.1     0.0     1.0
2   0.2     0.2     0.2
3   0.3     1.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Base R` way to do this:

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), sample1 = c(0, 1, 1), sample2 = c(1, 1, 0))
```

**PROCEDURE**

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] <- t(sapply(c(1:nrow(df)), function(x) ifelse(df[x,2:ncol(df)]==1, df[x,1],0)))
```

**OR**

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] <- ((df==1)*rep(df[,1],ncol(df)))[,2:ncol(df)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
df
    a sample1 sample2
1 0.1     0.0     0.1
2 0.2     0.2     0.2
3 0.3     0.3     0.0
```